# Fetching result of number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I was looking up how to count the number of rows in a table with php/mysql. I came up with this:

```
// Count rows
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$max = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

It seems the query failed:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object
>   given in /home/rlcoachi/public_html/hat/news.php on line 14

The table name is correct and there are 20+ rows in the table.

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs, you can't do that. Change `mysql_fetch_row` to `mysqli_fetch_row` - this isn't rum & coke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing MySQL APIs, you can't do that. Change mysql_fetch_row to mysqli_fetch_row - this isn't rum & coke. –  Fred -ii-

Comment: Can I get this on a t-shirt

Comment: @Strawberry Oh sure! Matter 'o fact, I worked in the industry for quite a few years lol

Comment: I want it on a cattle brand!

Comment: @OllieJones 50/50 or 100% cotton?

Comment: I just got this...because Rum and Coke have similar colours...haha this is funny.

Comment: @dayuloli Actually, the "rum & coke" analogy is that they "do mix" as a drink lol and some get much joy out of them; just not in this case ;-) there's also "white" rum.

Comment: @Fred Oh! Yeah...it's still funny

Comment: @dayuloli I use that expression every once in a while and saving it for such a (special) occasion ;-)

Comment: Next time I see someone do this, I'm going to steal this phrase. Maybe it'll become a standard reply to these questions on SO haha...

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $SQL);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

`$num_rows` will then be a number, being your total table row number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what should you do to fetch total number of rows.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from articles");
$totalRow = $mysqli->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
```

Or, as per your code, you can do like below :-

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$max = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Yes this is also a very good way to do it, either way should work for you, the SQL statements are just a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using PDO for this:

```
$db = new PDO("...");
$sql="SELECT count(*) FROM articles";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you're selecting `COUNT(*)`, it's already saved into the memory and you can therefore do

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$count = mysqli_result($result, 0);
```